# Creating Vector by Word Occurrence Table r

Tags: r, string, vector, bigdata

I need to find an automated way to take my original vector and transform each word, regardless of position in the vector, into a new vector. Each new vector reflects the presence of its basis word in each element of the original vector.

I need to turn this:

```r
OriginalVector <- c("Nimble red fox", "Lazy Grey Dog", "Red Fox funny")
```

into this:

```r
Nimble Red    Fox    Lazy   Grey   Dog    Funny
1      1      1      0      0      0      0
0      0      0      1      1      1      0
0      1      1      0      0      0      1
```

Each row should should correspond to each element in the original vector.  That is, the digit 1 reflects the presence of each word in the first element of the original vector "The nimble red fox", row two reflects the occurrence of each word in "Lazy Grey Dog", ...etc.

My real world problem has 300,000 more elements with several hundred thousand unique words. I could use `r grep()` or `r grepl()`, but trying to build each vector individually would be mind-boggling. Is their an automated way to solve this problem?

Note: I am not looking for a word co-occurrence matrix. Instead I need a frequency table row (original vector element) x word.

Comment: No!! All words from the original vector should stay in the pool.

Comment: 10s of hours programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the natural language processing frameworks can do this fairly easily. I like `tidytext` for simple things like this. There are faster ones computationally, but this is fairly simple.

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

OriginalVector <- c("Nimble red fox", "Lazy Grey Dog", "Red Fox funny")

df <- tibble(id = seq_along(OriginalVector), text = OriginalVector)

df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  count(id, word) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = word, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 3 x 7
    fox nimble   red   dog  grey  lazy funny
  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1      1     1     0     0     0     0
2     0      0     0     1     1     1     0
3     1      0     1     0     0     0     1
```

You can also exit the framework early and just use `table`.

```
table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text))

   word
id  dog fox funny grey lazy nimble red
  1   0   1     0    0    0      1   1
  2   1   0     0    1    1      0   0
  3   0   1     1    0    0      0   1
```

Note that `unnest_tokens()` has an option `to_lower = TRUE` by default. You can change this to `FALSE` if you do not want that.