# R count sum of partial string matches over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am working with an untidy registration form for a summer camp. The form output is given below:

```
          leaders         teen_adventure
1 camp, overnight                   <NA>
2            <NA>                   <NA>
3 camp, overnight camp, float, overnight
```

I want to generate new columns that sum the tally for each possible answer.

```
          leaders         teen_adventure camps overnights floats
1 camp, overnight                   <NA>     1          1      0
2            <NA>                   <NA>     0          0      0
3 camp, overnight camp, float, overnight     2          2      1
```

I feel in my bones that this has a dplyr solution, something like:

```
reprex %>%
  mutate(camps = sum(case_when(
    str_detect(select(., everything()), "camp") ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )))
```

or perhaps using across().

Here is the sample data set:

```
# data
reprex <- structure(list(leaders = c("camp, overnight", NA, "camp, overnight"), 
          teen_adventure = c(NA, NA, "camp, float, overnight")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe try a `pivot_longer()` to stack and then something like this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674656/creating-vector-by-word-occurrence-table-r/58674964#58674964

Comment: Is there a possibility of more columns other than camp, float, overnight?

Comment: @Dayne there is in fact another column for aftercare not in this reprex. If your question was are there more nominal columns with the actual data, yes to that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the words with `str_extract_all` by looping over the columns (`map`), then get the frequency count with `mtabulate`, bind the `list` elements, `summarise` the numeric columns to get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(qdapTools)
library(data.table)
reprex %>% 
   map_dfr(~ str_extract_all(.x, "\\w+") %>%
             mtabulate, .id = 'grp') %>%
   group_by(grp = rowid(grp)) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
       .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-grp) %>% 
   bind_cols(reprex, .)
```

-output

```
#            leaders         teen_adventure camp overnight float
#1 camp, overnight                   <NA>    1         1     0
#2            <NA>                   <NA>    0         0     0
#3 camp, overnight camp, float, overnight    2         2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
reprex %>%
  replace_na(list(leaders='unknown',teen_adventure='unknown'))%>%
  mutate(camp=as.numeric(str_detect(leaders, 'camp')+str_detect(teen_adventure,'camp')),
         float=as.numeric(str_detect(leaders,'float')+str_detect(teen_adventure,'float')),
         overnight=as.numeric(str_detect(leaders,'overnight')+str_detect(teen_adventure,'overnight')))
```

Output:

```
          leaders         teen_adventure camp float overnight
1 camp, overnight                unknown    1     0         1
2         unknown                unknown    0     0         0
3 camp, overnight camp, float, overnight    2     1         2
```

Comment: This solution is the closest to what I was getting at. This method preserves the nominal data not included in the reprex in a single row the way that pivot() options wouldn't. I am curious though if instead of typing out the individual columns being computed such as `str_detect(leaders ....) + str_detect(teen....)` there is a method of summing a selection of columns.

Comment: So I think there can be two ways: First, we write a function separately (or use lapply) such that `str_detect` works for each vector of a data frame. That way we just mention that function (will certainly try that). Second way is splitting the columns leaders and teen_adventures using `separate` and then processing the df (will use pivot somewhere) but it requires that these columns are tidy enough, as in no random text or commas (which is why I didn't use this method).

Comment: If your first two columns are tidy enough then most of the other answers should also work fine I think. I didn't use that approach because you said in your question that your data is untidy.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for any number columns and values:

```r
reprex %>%
 as_tibble %>%
 # split the values by `, `
 mutate_all(strsplit, ", ") %>%
 # map through each column then each cell in order make it a named vector
 # for example the first cell : c("camp", "overnight") => c("camp"=1, "overnight"=1)
 # then pivot it longer by the row_number (this is done for quickly suming the values)
 map_dfr( function(x) x %>% map_dfr( ~ set_names(rep(1, length(.x<-.x[!is.na(.x)])), .x)) %>%
     mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
     pivot_longer(!id) ) %>%
 # group by id and name so group the same variables that are found in the same row
 group_by(id, name) %>%
 # get the sum
 summarise_all(sum, na.rm=T) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 # return the tibble to wide format
 pivot_wider %>%
 # remove the id column
 select(-id) %>%
 # add the original data.frame to it
 tibble(reprex, .)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  leaders         teen_adventure          camp float overnight
  <chr>           <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 camp, overnight NA                         1     0         1
2 NA              NA                         0     0         0
3 camp, overnight camp, float, overnight     2     1         2
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
v <- unique(unlist(strsplit(na.omit(unlist(reprex)), ",\\s+")))
reprex <- cbind(
  reprex,
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      1:nrow(reprex),
      function(k) table(factor(unlist(strsplit(na.omit(unlist(reprex[k, ])), ",\\s+")), levels = v))
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
          leaders         teen_adventure camp overnight float
1 camp, overnight                   <NA>    1         1     0
2            <NA>                   <NA>    0         0     0
3 camp, overnight camp, float, overnight    2         2     1
```

Comment: Nice base R option